# why does google give eight DNS records for appspot custom domain setup

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I am using a [custom domain with my app-engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) website.
Right now my website is "working" intermittently. In other words, if I go to the costume domain it takes me to my website; if I go again it takes me to an error page for not found. I bought the domain name through GoDaddy. When I call GoDaddy they say it's because I have four A and four AAA resource records, and that instead I should use one. The thing is I tend to trust Google. So perhaps someone who has successfully **recently** used a custom domain with app-engine can help me a bit. Do I need all four options for `A` and all four options for `AAA`? Why does Google give me eight DNS resource records?

Comment: Not sure if that question fits SO.. https://support.google.com/a/answer/2576578?hl=en Also `A` is for IPv4 and `AAAA` is for IPv6.. For all that I guess you'll have to read up

Comment: 1) Are you seeing any errors in GAE app's logs? This might not be related to DNS settings at all. 2) Did you double check all 8 addresses and do they match what Google is asking you to set?

Answer (score 0):

Old question. No answer.

Short answer: use all 8. Why? Because Lord Google told you to.

Long answer: one A and one AAAA address should work. Having multiple records routes requests round robin.

P.S.
A records map to IPv4 addresses.
AAAA records map to IPv6 records.